# "new Set" is returning an empty set in nodejs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I was testing some websites using the below function with n, suddenly "new Set" started returning empty Array as the following:

```
function collectAllSameOriginAnchorsDeep(sameOrigin = true) {

const allElements = [];

// Some coding here 

const filtered = allElements

// Some coding here 

console.log(filtered) // The items are printed in the log probably


return Array.from(new Set(filtered)); // Nothing is getting returned!
}
```

If I replace the last line with return Array.from(filtered), then it works fine but I'm using "Set" to remove any repeated values.

Comment: How much length/size of your filtered array?

Comment: Not more than a 100 item only

Comment: You can create set object in top and add elements one by one , so you will get filtered elements

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Setting

Comment: If you are using at the end then you need to convert back to array using array.from “ES6 — Set vs Array — What and when?” by Maya Shavin https://link.medium.com/UGFoKMd9hV

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with this simple test script: https://gist.github.com/vsemozhetbyt/bff88b6b15e5bb2571ee8e8d9001a84a Maybe you need to provide the minimal complete code that does reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because Set receives iterable object as its input parameter, and will create set object respectively. Hence, we can construct a set from an array — but it will only include distinct elements from that array, aka no duplicate.

And of course, we can also convert a set back to array using Array.from() method.

```
let set = new Set([1,2,3]); // {1,2,3}
let arr = Array.from(set);//[1,2,3]
```

So you need to convert set back to array  , please check [here](https://link.medium.com/UGFoKMd9hV) to understand the difference between set and array.

Hope this will help you!